# Find current post id and exclude it from the get_permalink inside wordpress query

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, compare, increment

Hi everybody i need to remove the current url of the page from my preview news post type query.

```
<?php
global $post;$current_id = $post->ID;
            if($lang!=('it_IT')){query_posts(array(
                           'category_name'=> 'newseng',
                           'posts_per_page' => -1,
                           'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,));}
                           else{query_posts(array(
                           'category_name'=> 'news',
                           'posts_per_page' => -1,
                           'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,));} ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  $url = ( $current_id == $post->ID ) ? '&#35;' : get_permalink(); ?>
<div id="singlenews" class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">
<?php if($lang!=('it_IT')){get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'newsEng' );}else{get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'news' );} ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <button class="snow"><?php if($lang!=('it_IT')){echo'Read more';}else{echo'Leggi Tutto';} ?></button>
                    </a></div><?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

can anyone help me? i updated the code with the query to let understand that the loop is inside a query...

actual situation works correctly thanks to Nathan

Comment: code updated with the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're comparing the current URL to the URL of posts am I correct in thinking this is being used on a post (of any type inc page) and not an archive / category?

If so a more efficient way would be to compare the original post ID and the ID of the post in the loop. What are you trying to increment? Anyway here's my suggestion based on what I've understood so far.

```
<?php global $post;

// Post ID will change in loop so store existing ID as a variable.
$current_id = $post->ID;
```

Your posts query goes here...

And then:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $url = ( $current_id == $post->ID ) ? '#' : get_permalink(); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Read Now</a>
...
```

Comment: this is a single post page with full archive under the post section,

i tried your code but it actually prints the current url in all the anchor..
thanks for your help

Comment: @ValerioPenna Can you paste the full code you're using?

Comment: You aren't using the first part of the code. global $post; $current_id = $post->ID; This is crucial. Put it before you run query_posts as well. Before you start using get_template_part echo the output of $url so you can be sure it's working.

Comment: i added the code as you said also to the query run and decided to cut away the link button from the template cause at a first try it was echoing the right url before the template call but in the link it was echoing only the current url..

now the result is very near the only mistake left is that the url i should replace with '&#35;' which is a # actually comes echoed as url/# i need to remove the url and make the href="#"

Comment: You would use #, not &#35; and also if you view the source is the link showing as url/# or just #? Clicking it will change the address to url/# but that's normal. The value in href should still be #

Comment: this is actually working, the url in the source code is # thanks a lot Nathan!!

i'd like to give a +1 but i cant my reputation is too low

Comment: No problem. I'm pleased I was able to help.